# Apple Ipa package

Tags: certificate, ipa, mdm

We have some external IOS app developers who have made a app for IOS (IPA package). They have send the IPA file to me, and they have signed it with their own developer certificate - and say that we must sign it with our own, before we can deploy it.

Should we as company just sign up for a developer app and then re-sign it or what must be used ? It must be noticed, the App must not be on "app store". It is a local company app that we want to deploy to company phones etc, so outside App store

Another note. I tried to put the Ipa on a phone through apple configurator 2. It install, but afterwards the icon stay "grey" - and when trying to click on it, the error comes that the application cannot be installed.  Must the app not work through apple configurationer with manual installation ? - or has this also something to do with the developer signing etc ?

Comment: That is most likely the problem. If you look at the logs on the device, it will usually tell you why an IPA cannot be installed. You're better off signing the IPA with your certificate anyway.

Comment: Sorry - but where is the log file on an ipod, where the installation comes up with the error

I have now got access to our apple enterprise that we already have. But from there, how I sign the Ipa file with the certificates I cannot find any where ?

Comment: From - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/165100/how-to-read-iphone-system-logs - As you have Apple Configurator 2 installed, you should be able to access the logs from that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - but where is the log file on an ipod, where the installation comes up with the error.
 I have now got access to our apple enterprise that we already have. But from there, how I sign the Ipa file with the certificates I cannot find any where ?